# Facing trouble in converting tensorflow model to tflite model throught command line on windows

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, transfer-learning

Facing trouble in converting tensorflow model to tflite model throught command line on windows.

IMAGE_SIZE=224

```
tflite_convert \
  --graph_def_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \
  --input_array=input \
  --output_array=final_result \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

it always gives the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'tensorflow.contrib.lite.python.tflite_convert'

trouble is doing with tflite_convert on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to convert TensorFlow model to TensorFlow lite, when running toco --help gives me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340880/trying-to-convert-tensorflow-model-to-tensorflow-lite-when-running-toco-help)

Comment: it is different as i am trying to solve my problem by tflite and not able to solve it

Comment: What version of tf? Try the nightly, maybe? Also you can try the python form of the converter

Answer (score 0):

When i got the same problem. I have solved it using tensorFlow nighty version.
Here is the command which i used:

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

And here is the proper way of installing it in navigator env.
[tf-nighty](http://tflite_convert%20%20%20--output_file=too.tflite%20%20%20--keras_model_file=keras_model.h5)

I hope this will be helpful.